# Showing an histogram using opencv or pyplot

Tags: python, opencv, histogram, face-recognition

I have a trained face recognizer.
After doing `face_recognizer.getHistograms()` I want to show them.
How can I do this?
Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

To plot histogram of an image, use you use [pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

If you're image is in grayscale where gray scale intensities vary from 0 to 255, use:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.hist(img.ravel(), 256, [0,256])
```

If it's a color image, you can also use opencv's [calcHist](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html) function:

```
color = ('b', 'g', 'r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    plt.plot(histr,color = col)
    plt.xlim([0,256])
```

The image intensity of each channel should be between `[0, 255]`

Comment: I saw that function but I dont want to use it on an image. I want to show the histogram directly. Given a histogram as a numpy array - how can I show it?

Comment: Which function do you not want to use?

Comment: I have an pre-made histogram and I just want to show it. The pyplot.hist function shows a histogram of a given image. What I want is just to show an histogram without gibing the function the image itself.

Comment: Use plt.plot then

Comment: plt.plot(histogram), plt.show() does not work. It just creates an empty window with x and y axis

Comment: How did you find your histogram?

Comment: I got it by feeding my face recognizer with a face via the ‘train’ method. Then I can use ‘face_recognizer.getHistograms()[0] will give me a histogram for one of the trained faces.

Comment: Can you share the shape your histogram array?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to simulate histogram collection via opencv using the [OpenCV-Flow](https://online.opencvflow.org/) online tool.

See results here:

[image]

Comment: interesting web app!